Back-EMF in a DC motor as a Sine Wave?
I am taking time to re-familiarize myself with the design and principles behind the operation of dc motors. I am right now trying to understand back-emf. Forgive me if I seem to have a piecemeal understanding of electromagnetics; I don't deal with it on a day-to-day basis, but am interested in it.
Take the single square coil of wire with current $i_r$ and the area enclosed by the coil of $A$, with the vector $\vec{A}$ having magnitude A and direction normal to the plane of the coil. The coil is immersed in a magnetic field of flux density $\vec{B}$. Say the coil is constrained such that it can only rotate about a single axis, as is the case with all common motors. The polarity of the rotor's circuit is shown in the image below, which is as dictated by a two-piece commutator. The rotor is at an arbitrary angle $\theta$ in its rotation. Assume the rotor is already moving with an angular velocity $\omega$ in the counterclockwise direction, and theta is positive in this direction.

I understand that the induced electromotive force (emf) is directly proportional to the rate of change of flux across a coil of wire. The equation for flux through a single rotating coil is below.
$$ \phi = \vec{B}\cdot \vec{A} = ||\vec{B}||||\vec{A}||\cos\theta$$
Then, the rate of change of flux with respect to time is
$$ \frac{d\phi}{dt} = ||\vec{B}||||\vec{A}||\frac{d(\cos\theta)}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt} = -||\vec{B}||||\vec{A}||\omega \sin\theta $$
Following this, the equation for back emf is given as
$$\varepsilon = -\frac{d\phi}{dt}=||\vec{B}||||\vec{A}||\omega \sin\theta $$
These equations are plotted with respect to $\theta$ below.

What I'm confused about, is how I should interpret negative vs positive emf, or whether it's a good distinction to understand or focus on at all. According to $\varepsilon(\theta)$, the back emf will be positive from 0 to 180 exclusive, and be negative from 180 to 360 (or back to 0). However, in terms of torque, the back emf will always oppose the torque generated by the motor, and thus be in opposition to the rotor supply voltage $v_s$.
Below are my questions.

Is it an acceptable perspective to say that the commutator will flip the polarity of the rotor circuit at $0 \text{ deg}$ and $180 \text{ deg}$, which nullifies the sign of the emf wave, seemingly making $| ||\vec{B}||||\vec{A}||\omega sin\theta |$ a better interpretation of the emf for dc motors with commutators?

Does the sinusoidal nature of the back-emf get lost when multiple coils are added to the rotor?

Also, I assume that $\omega$ will not be constant in this scenario, and might be a sine wave itself, in phase with the emf?


Any insight into the nature of back emf in a single coil rotor would be helpful. Also, if you have a good suggestion for textbooks on these subjects, that would be much appreciated. I am currently reading through Hughes' and Drury's Electric Motors and Drives, 5th Edition. Thank you in advance.
